# Spring - PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring, profiles

I am trying to implement an application for different profiles using Spring 3 but i am not sure how it develop using Spring 3. I have couple of confusions

1. When you develop application using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, then how do you create session factor object that pass to the DAO classes?
2. How can i create profiles for each property file. Let say i want to pass an "Dev" parameter then application ready property files from dev.proertie file, and then pass it to the application.
3. I just read some tutorials on google, most of the tutorials follow the hard coded profile name in every class like @Profile("dev") in every DAO class. Is there any way to do it automatically means how to inject into DAO classes? i dont want to add profile name in every class

Here are the List of my application

This is Simple Model Object.

** Employee.Java**

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

This Class deals with Database. So i want to have session object in this class rather than Datasource object.

**Employee DAO class**

```
public class EmployeeDao {
  private DataSource dataSource;
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }
  public void insert(Employee employee){
   String sql = "insert into employee(name) VALUES (?)";
   Connection conn = null;
   try {
     conn = dataSource.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     ps.setString(1, employee.getName());
     ps.executeUpdate();
     ps.close();
     conn.close();
   } 
   catch (SQLException sqle) {
     System.out.println("Sql Exception " + sqle.getMessage());
   }
 }
```

This class actually reads the data from property file but not sure how to build up session object that inject in my DAO Class

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {
  @Bean
  public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
   PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
   ClassPathResource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[ ]
   { new ClassPathResource( "db.properties" ) };
   ppc.setLocations( resources );
   ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
   return ppc;
  }
  @Value( "${jdbc.url}" ) private String jdbcUrl;
  @Value( "${jdbc.driverClassName}" ) private String driverClassName;
  @Value( "${jdbc.username}" ) private String username;
  @Value( "${jdbc.password}" ) private String password;
  @Bean(name="datasource")
  public DataSource datasource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
    ds.setUsername(username);
    ds.setPassword(password);
    return ds;
  }
  @Bean(name="employee")
  public Employee employee() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setName("Sahil");
    return employee;
  }

  @Bean(name="employeeDao")
  public EmployeeDao employeeDao() {
  EmployeeDao employeeDao =  new EmployeeDao();
  employeeDao.setDataSource(datasource());
  return employeeDao;
}
```